# mongoose connection to mongodb 2.6.1 replica set auth failed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to connect mongodb from node.js using mongoose.
I'm facing problem while connecting to multiple servers.
I'm able to connect to single server.
If I try for connecting multiple servers (as I want to connect to replicasets ) it's throwing error auhtfailed.

```
var options = {
'db': {
    'native_parser': true
},
'server': {
    'auto_reconnect': true,
    'poolSize': 5,
    'socketOptions' : { 'keepAlive': 1 }
},
'replset': {
    'readPreference': 'nearest',
    'strategy': 'ping',
    'rs_name': 'rs01',
    'socketOptions' : { 'keepAlive': 1 }
}
};

var connect = mongoose.connect('mongodb://adminname:adminpassword@host1:27017,host2:27017,host3:27017/myDatabase', options , function (err) {
"use strict";
if (err) {
    console.log(err);
}else{
    console.log("connected")
}
```

It's showing auth failed throwing this error

> { [MongoError: auth failed]   name: 'MongoError',   message: 'auth failed',   ok: 0,   errmsg: 'auth failed',   code: 18 }

Answer (score 0):

```
 mongoConnectionString : "mongodb://dbusername:dbpassword@localhost:27017/db,host2:27017/db,host3:27017/db",

mongoDbOptions : {
    db: {
        native_parser: true
    },
    server: {
        poolSize: 5
    },
    replset: {
        rs_name: 'rplname',
        readPreference: 'ReadPreference.secondaryPreferred'
    },
    pluralization: false,
    host: 'localhost',
    port : '27017'
},
mongoose.connect(mongoConnectionString, mongoDbOptions, function (error) {
    "use strict";
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
    else {
        console.log("Connection to mongo successful");
    }
});
```

this works for me!! Thanks;..